# Search string in SQL LIKE in multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I'm trying to make a "related products" query to search 5 related products but it gives this error:
image of error: http://puu.sh/eeo5n/a845ef5ba3.png

This is my code

```
    // Info current t-shirt. Normally from database
    $name = "Luftrauser T-shirt";
    $description = "Stylish LUFTRAUSERS T-shirt designed by Amon26.";
    $relatedSearch = $name . $description;

    // Query which searches for related items
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE name, description LIKE '%:relatedSearch%'");
    $query -> bindParam("relatedSearch", $relatedSearch, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($query -> execute()) {
        while($related = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            echo $related->title . "</br>";
        }
    }
```

Why does it not return the rows which contain the values I search for with the LIKE?

Comment: Why does it not return the rows? Did you read the error message? It's saying that you have a **syntax error** in your query. You cannot make a list of columns a, b and match it with a single parameter without distinguishing between then with an OR or an AND in between, i.e. see @Matt's answer.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. There is no error anymore. But somehow it doesn't fetch the data from the query when I put it in the while. I now tried to echo $related->description but it echoes nothing. And there should be some more words in the database which match the $relatedSearch variable. Screenshot of the database: puu.sh/eep39/6920910c76.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the search to look in name AND description and match EITHER

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_products 
WHERE description LIKE '%:relatedSearch%' OR name LIKE '%:relatedSearch%'
```

If you want the search to look in name AND description and match BOTH

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_products 
WHERE description LIKE '%:relatedSearch%' AND name LIKE '%:relatedSearch%'
```

Comment: There's a small typo in your answer. The first sentence should have `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: No it should be AND, as it looks in both and matches EITHER.  Where the second query looks in both and matches BOTH

Comment: @Matt If either can be true then it would be `OR` which is what your example has.

Comment: @Jim either can be true, thats why it says match EITHER

Comment: @Jim if i used OR it would say "look in name OR description and match ONE"

Comment: You're both right, it's a matter of how you interpretate the sentance.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. There is no error anymore. But somehow it doesn't fetch the data from the query when I put it in the while. I now tried to echo $related->description but it echoes nothing. And there should be some more words in the database which match the $relatedSearch variable. Screenshot of the database: puu.sh/eep39/6920910c76.png

Comment: @user3428971 Please mark the current answer as accepted and post a new question with your new question.